# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - EF Core 6 - model is not validating correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm currently trying to start a new project with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC and Entity Framework Core 6 and npgsql.

When I try to add one entity which has a foreign identity the `ModelState.IsValid` keeps returning false - as the model doesn't expand the foreign entity.

Basically I followed the official documentation at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0

So my classes look like:

```cs
namespace PV.Models
{
    public class Fakultaet
    {
        [Key]
        public int FakultaetID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FakuName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Studiengang
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudiengangID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StudiengangName { get; set;}
        [Required,ForeignKey("Fakultaet")]
        public int FakultaetID { get; set; }
        
        public Fakultaet Fakultaet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Partial view:

```cs
@model PV.Models.Studiengang
<tr>
         <td>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input asp-for="StudiengangName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StudiengangName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select asp-for="FakultaetID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.FakultaetId">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="0">Bitte wählen...</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="FakultaetID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Speichern" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" id="btn-addinline-submit" />
            <input type="reset" onClick="location.reload()" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" id="btn-addinline-abort" value="Abbrechen" />
        </td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```cs
namespace PV.Controllers
{
    public class StudiengangController : Controller
    {
        private readonly PraktikumsKontext _context;

        public StudiengangController(PraktikumsKontext ctx)
        {
            _context = ctx;
        }
       
        // --- snip ---

        // GET: Student/Add
        public IActionResult AddStudiengangInline()
        {
            ViewBag.FakultaetId = new SelectList(_context.Fakultaeten.AsNoTracking(), "FakultaetID", "FakuName");
            return PartialView();
        }

        // POST: Student/Add
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudiengangInline([Bind("StudiengangName, FakultaetID")] Studiengang studiengang )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(studiengang);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewData["FakultaetId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fakultaeten, "FakultaetID", "FakuName", studiengang.FakultaetID);

            return PartialView(studiengang);
        }
    }
}
```

When I now fill out my form and POST `StudiengangName=Test1234;FakultaetID=1` (with an existing `Fakultaet` with `ID = 1` of course) my model does look like this:

```
StudiengangID = 0
StudiengangName = "Test1234"
Fakultaet = null
FakultaetID = 1
```

Therefore the `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false` as `Fakultaet` is `null`.

Here I'd assume that EF Core 6 does its magic and resolves the entity I'm referencing.

If I add the following snippet before checking if the model is valid, everything seems to work:

```cs
studiengang.Fakultaet =
                _context.Fakultaeten.SingleOrDefault(stg => stg.FakultaetID == studiengang.FakultaetID);
            ModelState.ClearValidationState(nameof(Fakultaet));
            TryValidateModel(studiengang);
```

But this seems to be a dirty workaround as it was not necessary in .NET Core 3.1 with almost the same setup.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Comment: to my knowledge, adding a foreign key relationship doesn't automatically expand navigation properties in earlier EF core versioning either.

Comment: the 'workaround' would be `Include(stg => stg.Fakultaet)` before `SingleOrDefault`, but I feel -- in this question -- you're looking for a means to automatically expand it.  perhaps a `virtual` property? not sure

Comment: @BrettCaswell already tried it as virtual. The `SingleOrDefault` is already the working workaround to Fill in the Fakultaet. I wonder why it is documented this way and - is working in .NETcore 3.1

Comment: hmm.. I see.. yea, I would steer away from doing that `SingleOrDefault` portion. try adding `[Required]` attribute to the Navigation property `Fakultaet`.   (e.g., [the-instructor-navigation-property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-instructor-navigation-property) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/nullable-reference-types#create-the-application-and-enable-nullable-reference-types) said:

> Beginning with .NET 6, new projects include the
> `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` element in the project file. Once the
> feature is turned on, existing reference variable declarations become
> **non-nullable reference types**.

In .NET 6 the **non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

To achieve your requirement, you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file.

The second way, you can initialize the model like below:

```
public class Studiengang
{
    [Key]
    public int StudiengangID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudiengangName { get; set;}
    [Required,ForeignKey("Fakultaet")]
    public int FakultaetID { get; set; }
    
    public Fakultaet Fakultaet { get; set; } = new Fakultaet();
}
```

The third way, you can add `?` to allow nullable:

```
public class Studiengang
{
    [Key]
    public int StudiengangID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudiengangName { get; set;}
    [Required,ForeignKey("Fakultaet")]
    public int FakultaetID { get; set; }
    
    public Fakultaet? Fakultaet { get; set; }
}
```

The last way is like what you did to remove the key in model validation.

Comment: The `?`-one did the trick. Will try the nullable later. 
Creating an empty Object of `Fakultaet` resulted in an invalid `Fakultaet.FakuName` as I did not set this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add form with validation and antiforgery to your view

```
@model PV.Models.Studiengang

<form method="post"  asp-controller="Studiengang" asp-action="AddStudiengangInline" >

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


<tr>
         ,,,,,

     <td>
 <input type="submit" value="Speichern" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" id="btn-addinline-submit" />
          ...
        </td>
</tr>
                    
</form>
```

It is better to add a  list of DDL items  to viewModel

```
 public class Studiengang
    {
       ....
        public int FakultaetID { get; set; }
        
        public Fakultaet Fakultaet { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<SelectListItem> FakultaetItems { get; set; }
    }
```

action

```
public IActionResult AddStudiengangInline()
{
var model= new Studiengang { FakultaetItems = new _context.Fakultaeten
.Select (i=> new SelectListItem { Value=i.FakultaetID, Text=i.FakuName}).ToList();
return PartialView(model);
}
```

IMHO remove Bind from post action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudiengangInline(Studiengang studiengang )
```

and finaly a select control

```
 <select asp-for="FakultaetID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.FakultaetItems"> </select>
```

Comment: The form itself is in the parent view where I inject the partial from above.
Validation itself is working. Though the  `ModelState` is not getting valid because EF does not reference the ID from the DropDown to an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an InputModel with only the StudentId, StudentName, FacultyId and a collection of all faculties, populated from the database, as properties and pass that model to the dbContext. For example:

```
public class InputModel
{
 public StudentId {get;set;}
 public StudentName {get;set;}
 public FacultyId {get;set;}
 public ICollection<Faculty> Faculties {get;set;}
}
```

In the controller you should have two actions:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudiengangInline()
{
  var model = new InputModel()
{
   Faculties = this.data.Faculties.toList() //or any filtering and stuff
}
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

Then have your second action as you did but it will accept the model from the first action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudiengangInline(InputModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                do Stuff
            }

            do stuff
        }
```